# Compare form date values in the view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a django form which has date fields filled by the user and need to compare them for validity.

Anyway the following conditions evaluate to false always. As I'm new to django, I'm not sure is this the right way to do it.

**views.py**

```
start_date = form_new_task.cleaned_data['start_date']
end_date = form_new_task.cleaned_data['end_date']

if start_date < date.today():
    err_str = 'Start date cannot be a past date.'
elif end_date < date.today():
    err_str = 'End date should be a future date.'
elif start_date == end_date:
    err_str = 'Start and End date cannot be the same date.'
elif end_date < start_date:
    err_str = 'End date should be beyond the Start date.'
```

Comment: Is this code in your form's `validate` or `clean` method?

Comment: @NathanJones by the looks of it it is not, because if it were there wouldn't be instance of form

Comment: @Nathan, this is in the function where request is processed. I instantiated the form with request and checked for is_valid(). Values returned after cleaned_data does not give the correct output for above conditions. Should I convert the obtained dates before comparison? If yes what the correct way doing it?

Comment: as i comment. You should do with type of value in Client and pass it to Server later. if you just want to compare and don't store value ~> convert to seconds. And if you want to store this value ~> convert to the type you want to store and compare it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do the comparison correctly.

```
if form_new_task.is_valid():
      start_date = form_new_task.cleaned_data['start_date']
      delta = start_date - date.today()

if delta.days < 0:
      err_str = 'Start date cannot be a past date.'
elif delta.days == 0:
        ....
        ....
```

Comment: Using delta between two days works for any. I'm not sure whether comparison operators works for two date objects directly.

Answer (score 0):

I recomment:

```
# in JS file:
input_date = $("datefield").val() # or .text for this type
# Convert to second or datetime format
# Do the if else conditions
if input_date < date.today():
   # Do something you want.
```

Comment: I need to validate dates in the form itself in django server side.

Comment: I think the thought behind this answer is to insure you're sending a valid date to your django backend.

Comment: @NathanJones. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure IF you comparing two datetime then

```
start_date = '2016-11-07 16:00:14.779541+05'
end_date = '2016-11-07 18:00:14.779541+05'

if start_date < end_date:
     print 'yes'
else:
     print 'No'
```

It is going to print yes because two dates are same but time is different.
May be this causes problem in your code.

To ensure two dates must compare Do something like this:

```
if start_date.date() < end_date.date():
 print 'yes'
else:
 print 'No'
```

In this case It will only compare two dates and it gonna print No.

Comment: `start_date = forms.DateField(label='Start Date', widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control datepicker'}))
end_date = forms.DateField(label='End Date', widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control datepicker'}))`

Comment: I changed two distinct dates such that `start_date` is a past date and a `end_date` is earlier than `start_date`. In any case I don't get the expected results. I wonder whether obtained dates converted to `date` type before comparison.

Comment: Get print type of both dates, see what it shows. make sure both types are similar. print start_date, type(start_date)